# Android: Strange behavior of onClick()

Tags: android, android-layout

Subject says "strange" behavior, but I actually don't know if it's strange. It's only strange for me (I'm newbie). I have very basic project with the only layout in my activity. I set listeners on layout for onTouch and onClick. Both methods (onTouch and onClick) work (e.g. called).
However, onClick is called even if I pressed screen -> moved finger for 5-10 seconds -> released screen -> onClick(). Is this intended behavior for onClick? onClick() fires even if I single "clicked" screen for 10 seconds? And is this normal?

If this is normal, then I switch back to my implementation of click handling with onTouch where I measure time (e.g. 200ms max) between UP/DOWN actions.

Comment: I don't get you, what do you want to do? What's your question?

Comment: Why do you think this is weird behaviour ? Seems that your layout just has attribute clickable set to true, so why you get onClick fired after releasing touch

Comment: Also post your xml if you can

Comment: When you release, is your finger still on the clickable view? If so, that is typical onClick behaviour, if not, no. In any case, not sure setting on onTouch listener and onClick for the same view makes much sense - there's a lint check that pops up, warning you when you override onTouch without detecting clicks and calling `view.performClick()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your sample and the thing that occurs is that when you try to "CLICK" on your screen it's **DIFICULT** to make `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` because you'll move a little bit your finger, so if you are asking for what's better I would say the `onClick()` because it's only fired when you click on the specific item.

### EDIT

> However, onClick is called even if I pressed screen -> moved finger for 5-10 seconds -> released screen -> onClick(). Is this intended behavior for onClick?

That's because `onClick()` method is called first when you have done an `ACTION_DOWN` and it ends when you do an `ACTION_UP`, so even if you are moving the finger on your screen for 2 hours when you make an `ACTION_UP` it also will finish the `onClick()` event.

Comment: I don't have any items, it's only a layout. Let's say I'm implementing touchpad :)

Comment: So what you are asking what's better?

Comment: I'm not asking what's better. I updated my question, maybe it's a bit clear now.

Comment: Thanks... Switching back to handling clicks with onTouch.